# Preventing duplicate items to be added into a checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I've written a code that add a list to checkedlistbox and I want to check the checkedlistbox if there is a same item thats in the list. My code doesnt add any items at all to the checkedlistBox.Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?.

```
 int y;

           if (clb_output.Items.Count != 0){
           for (y = 0; y < q.Count; y++){
               for (int z = 0; z < clb_output.Items.Count; z++)
               {
                   if (q[y].ToString() != clb_output.Items[z].ToString())
                   {
                       clb_output.Items.Add(q[y].ToString());
                       break;
                   }
                   else { }

               }
           }
           }
           else
           {
               for (int t = 0; t < q.Count;t++ )
                   clb_output.Items.Add(q[t].ToString()); 

           }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you set a breakpoint at the first for statement, then run the program in the debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Are you starting with an empty `CheckedListBox` and you want to add only distinct items from a list that may contain duplicates or are you starting with a `CheckedListBox` that may contain items and you want to add each item from a list only if the same item is not already in the `CheckedListBox`?

Comment: I've edited your code to fix the formatting.  Is it too much to ask that you post code that we can read easily?

Comment: What's the point of an empty `else` block?  It's just clutter.

Comment: I set a breakpoint and the program isn't even going to the else statement even if the if statement is false. And @jmcilhinney I'm starting with an empty CheckedListBox and I want to add Items that are in the q List that are not already in the CheckedListBox.

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger what "ToString()" is returning?  Maybe it's something inappropriate like the [fully qualified type name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Why are you not using `Contains`, or `Any`? What is the expected outcome from a fixed input data? What is the actual outcome of the same data? It's easier to help if you include as much information (as is important to know) as you can. Simply asking "Why is this code not working" is not good enough.

Comment: Although this is not what you want, but best bet could be clear the list before inserting the items again.

Comment: Ive checked my debugger and the strings are are returning a correct value like INPUT 10 which is what I want,I have updated my code above,but now the program is entering the if (q[y].ToString() != clb_output.Items[z].ToString()) statement even when it's supposed to be false.

Comment: "I'm starting with an empty CheckedListBox and I want to add Items that are in the q List that are not already in the CheckedListBox". That doesn't make sense. If the `CheckedListBox` is empty to begin with then there are no items in it so none of the items in your list can already be in the `CheckedListBox`. That means that you can simply add the entire list.

Comment: I know I have fixed that problem now

Comment: but now the program keeps on executing the if statement even when its false. And here let me explain it again...I have an empty checkedlistbox and a list named q.The item in the q list are checked items from another checkedlistbox named clb_input. Now after my first insertion I want to add my new selections from the clb_input (which are added to my q list) to the clb_output but I want to check if there is already an item in the clb_output that is the same as the item in my q list.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.I have solved my problem now...I added a clear method and instead rewrote everytime the program went into the if statement.The updated code is above

Comment: Instead of adding "solved" to the title, mark one of the provided answers as the answer. Also, instead of amending the question with the solution code, put it in an answer. You should try and respect the mechanics of this site to keep it useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When facing issues like these, test-driven development is a good way to solve the problem.

Start by setting up your class to be tested and a test (we'll ignore mocks and stuff for the moment)

```
public class MyClass {
  private readonly List<Item> q = new List<Item>();
  private readonly List<Item> checkedItems = new List<Item>();

  public ICollection<Item> Q
  {
     get { return q; }
  }

  public ICollection<Item> CheckedItems
  {
     get { return checkedItems; }
  }

  public void TransferItems() {
    // todo:
  }
}

public class Item { }
```

You can add a test method using Visual Studio unit tests, or use something like NUnit.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTest {
  [Test]
  public void NewItemsAreAddedWhenCheckedItemsIsEmpty() {
    // arrange
    Item expectedItem = new Item();
    MyClass tester = new MyClass();
    tester.Q.Add(expectedItem);

    // act
    tester.TransferItems();

    // assert
    int actualCount = tester.CheckedItems.Count;
    int expectedCount = 1;

    Assert.Equals(actualCount, expectedCount);

    var actualItem = tester.CheckedItems[0];
    Assert.AreSame(actualItem, expectedItem);
  }

  [Test]
  public void NewItemsAreAddedWhenCheckedItemsContainsElements() {
    // arrange
    Item expectedItem = new Item();
    MyClass tester = new MyClass();
    tester.Q.Add(expectedItem);
    tester.CheckedItems.Add(new Item());

    // act
    tester.TransferItems();

    // assert
    int actualCount = tester.CheckedItems.Count;
    int expectedCount = 2;

    Assert.Equals(actualCount, expectedCount);

    var expectedContains = tester.CheckedItems.Contains(expectedItem);
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedContains);
  }
}
```

When this is in place, you can simply run the test, see that it fails and change your code accordingly.

```
public class MyClass {
  private readonly List<Item> q = new List<Item>();
  private readonly List<Item> checkedItems = new List<Item>();

  public ICollection<Item> Q
  {
     get { return q; }
  }

  public ICollection<Item> CheckedItems
  {
     get { return checkedItems; }
  }

  public void TransferItems() {
    IEnumerable<Item> itemsToAdd = q.Where(item => !checkedItems.Contains(item));
    checkedItems.AddRange(itemsToAdd);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If clb_output.Items.Count() is Zero in your second for loop then you will never reach the statement that adds to the box. You need to set your breakpoint right at the start of the code to see whats happening and fix your logic.

```
        int y;

        if (clb_output.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < q.Count; y++)
            {
                if (!clb_output.Items.Contains(q[y].ToString()))
                {
                    clb_output.Items.Add(q[y].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < q.Count; t++)
                clb_output.Items.Add(q[t].ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Yea you're right...I have fixed that problem now with an updated code above but now it keeps going in the if statement

Comment: See the example code I have added. You need to check if the clb_output collection contains the item you are checking. What you have adds the item if they are not the same, which they will not be in most cases. This is why it is going into the inner if statement each time. Also note that the changes I made are pseudo code. You may have to implement a contains method depending on your clb_output object type.

Comment: I decided to clear the checkedlistbox because all my sorted items (and new ones added) are already in my q list. Thanks everyone...my updated code is above...its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

1) please make sure your q collection isnt empty

2) i usually fill a list like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < q.Count; y++)
{
    if(!clb_output.Indexof(q[y].ToString.Trim.ToLower() > -1)
    {
             clb_output.Items.Add(q[y].ToString());
    }
}
```